# knockout js foreach loop context

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

A have template:

```
<table data-bind="foreach: {data: messages, as: 'message'}">
    <tr>   <td data-bind="text: $root.go"></td>   </tr>
</table>
```

My js:

```
function CreateViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    this.go = ko.computed(function() {
        return 'not really important what here for now';
    });
}

ko.applyBindings( new MessagesVM );
```

The context in 'go' while runtime is 'window', I want it to be the current item.
Is it possible?
If I change tmpl line to "`<td data-bind="text: go"></td>`" I will have an error ['go' is not defined].

Comment: isn't go a function?

Comment: 'go' is method of created object I guess

Comment: BTW, generally best to explicitly include the `tbody` element.

Comment: Does `MessagesVM` contain a collection of `CreateViewModel` in `messages`?

Comment: Yes, I have 'messages' array which is iterated in foreach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The context in 'go' while runtime is 'window', I want it to be the current item. Is it possible?

I don't think you can with a computed, no. If you make it a simple function you can: `data-bind="text: $root.go.call(message)"` (generically it would be `.call($data)`, but since you're naming it in your `foreach`):

```js
function MessagesVM() {
  var self = this;
  this.messages = ko.observableArray([
    "Message 1",
    "Message 2"
  ]);
  this.go = function() {
    return 'this is: "' + this + '"';
  };
}

ko.applyBindings(new MessagesVM);
```

```html
<table data-bind="foreach: {data: messages, as: 'message'}">
  <tr>
    <td data-bind="text: $root.go.call(message)"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.3.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
```

---

Alternately, if you want some of the functionality of a computed but acting on the individual item, I'd probably use a binding handler:

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.specialText = {
  update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
    var value = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
    element.innerHTML = "'value' is " + value;
  }
};
function MessagesVM() {
  var self = this;
  this.messages = ko.observableArray([
    "Message 1",
    "Message 2"
  ]);
}

ko.applyBindings(new MessagesVM);
```

```html
<table data-bind="foreach: {data: messages, as: 'message'}">
  <tr>
    <td data-bind="specialText: message"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.3.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Turn it into a function and pass the context in. As a computed, it has a cached value and so cannot be context-dependent.

```js
function CreateViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  this.messages = [
    'one',
    'two'
  ];
  this.go = function(data) {
    var context = data;
    return 'Context:' + context;
  };
}

ko.applyBindings(new CreateViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<table data-bind="foreach: {data: messages, as: 'message'}">
  <tr>
    <td data-bind="text: $root.go(message)"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```